# Zone wise and line item wise display of amedments using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in which i have columns like SO number, line item number, amendment number and zone.

I need to display the total number of amendments zone wise.

I have 6 zones - a,b,c,d,e,f

so numbers like 1,2 for zone a; 3,4 for zone b; similarly for other zones.

in each so number there might be 1 or more than one line item numbers like 10,20,30 etc.
for each so number there will be just one amendment (i.e., even if an so number has many line item numbers, it will have just one amendment)

now, say in zone a, there are 4 so numbers 1,2,3,4. and in so number 1 there is one line item number 10 and its amendment number is 2. say for so number 2 there are 4 line item numbers 10,20,30,40 and the amendment number is 0. so for this zone a, total number of amendments would be 2 (desired result). how do i do it?

```
Zone     so_number     line_item_number  amendment_number  
a----------        1 ----------------             10 ----------------               2  
a----------        2 ----------------             10 ----------------               0  
a----------        2 ----------------             20 ----------------               0  
a----------        2 ----------------             30 ----------------               0  
a ----------       2 ----------------             40 ----------------               0  
a ----------       3 ----------------             10----------------                1  
a ----------       4 ----------------             10 ----------------               3  
a-----------       4 -----------------            20 ----------------               3  
b -----------      6 ----------------             60 -----------------              6  
c------------      7 ----------------             80 -----------------              0  
c ----------       8 ------------------           10 -----------------              0  
d  ------------    9 -----------------            10 -----------------              2  
e  ------------    10-----------------            20  -----------------             3    
f  ------------    11-----------------             30 -----------------             1  
f -------------    11 ---------------              10 ------------------            1  
f -------------    11 ---------------              20 -------------------           1  
f ------------     12 ----------------             10 ------------------            2
```

For zone a total number of amendments would be 6, for zone b it would be 6, for c - 0, for d - 2, e - 3, f - 3

a zone may have any number of so numbers, an so number may have any number of line item numbers, but, an so number may have only one amendment number

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i really don't understand your question and your result.

It could seems very simple from my understands

```
select zone, 
sum(amendment_number) 
from tablea 
group by zone
```

now my result would be : 9-6-0-2-3-5

Do you only want the last so_number?

```
select zone, 
sumamend 
from 
   (select zone, 
   sum(amendment_number) as sumamend, 
   row_number over (partition by zone order by so_number desc) as ord 
   from tablea 
   group by zone, so_number) b
where ord = 1
```

But again i don't have the same result : 6-6-0-2-3-2

if i correctly understand your comment and hoping you have all case in your example you want something like this :

```
select zone, 
sum(amendment_number) 
   from (select distinct zone,so_number, amendment_number from #test) p
group by zone
```

it gives the following result : 6-6-0-2-3-3

Comment: no i want the result 6 6 0 2 3 3, as i have mentioned, nedd the sum of amendments zone wise. for an so number, there can be just one amendment but many line item numbers. for zone a in my example, for so number 1 its 2, for so number 2 its 0, for so number 3 its 1 and for so number 4 its 3. so, the total would be 2+0+1+3 which is 6

Comment: but how do you determine which lineitem you are picking for the sum? Are you taking the smaller lineitem or the greater? For your example a so number 4 could be 3 or 3. Do you have doublon? for a same so number the amendment number will always be the same? like you show in your example

Comment: yes, i need to consider all line items in an so number. so its not the sum of all the amendment numbers. but, sum of amendment numbers for an so number and not line item number. like i said, amendment is for an so number and not for line item number. and for a zone, sum of all the amendments of all the so numbers(not line item numbers)

Comment: u cant use the keyword distinct, coz, if in a zone we have 3 so numbers and we have same amendment numbers for the so number, then distinct would give wrong results

Comment: please guide me, i am totally lost

Comment: sorry, really sorry for not reading your answer completely. thanks much :)